# Get the max value from a table, increment by one and insert into the active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table `SOGP1`, that has a column `ShotNo` that needs to increment by one each time I click in any cell in the first 37 columns

Step 1 - click somewhere
Step 2 - Find the max value `ShotNo` column in the table `SOGP1`, increment in by 1, store that value in the active cell
step 3 - Add a new row to the SOGP1 table and add the next value in the `ShotNo` column

So if the max value is 2, I will insert 3 in the cell I Click, and I will also add a row in the table and in the `ShotNo` column insert the value of 3.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim lstObj1 As ListObject
Set lstObj1 = Worksheets("Sheet 1").ListObjects("SOGP1")
ActiveCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(lstObj1.ListColumns("ShotNo").Range) + 1
```

I get a `subscript - out of range` error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: the ActiveCell.Value line

Comment: That means the table has no column with the header `"ShotNo"`.

Comment: Sub p1sh()
'
' p1sh Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Dim lstObj1 As ListObject
    Set lstOjb1 = Worksheets("Sheet 1").ListObjects("SOGP1")
    ActiveCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(lstObj1.ListColumns("ShotNo").Range) + 1
    
  
    
End Sub
Could it be something else? Ii cut and pasted the table name and columns

Comment: That means that the `ActiveWorkbook` does not contain a sheet named "Sheet1", or the sheet named "Sheet1" doesn't contain a table named "SOGP1", or both.

Comment: Did you try using "Sheet1" instead of "Sheet 1"? Default tab has no space.

Comment: that fixed the first error. Now i get Object Variable or With Block variable not set at the next line :     ActiveCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(lstObj1.ListColumns("ShotNo").Range) + 1

Comment: That line should work if `lstObj1` was successfully assigned on the previous line

Comment: So i had a typo. Set lstOjb1 instead of lstObj1. Now that works! Can i just add another line to insert the same value in the ShotNo column in the SOGP1 table?